# Flask thread pool exhausted

Tags: python, flask, kubernetes

I have a Flask-based app that is used as a front (HTTP API only) for an image processing task (face detection along with some clustering). The app is deployed to Kubernetes clusters and, unfortunately during load testing it dies.

The problem is that all Flask threads are reserved for request processing and the application can't reply to Kubernetes liveness probe (`/health` endpoint) via HTTP - so the whole pod gets restarted.

How can I resolve it? I thought about a grep-based liveness problem however it doesn't solve the problem. Another idea is to use celery, however, if Flask doesn't support async-processing I'll need to call `wait()` on a celery task which gives me exactly to the same place.

For now I don't consider returning `202` response along with URL for process monitoring.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

How did you deploy Gunicorn etc?

FastAPI might be better suited for your use case, but migration might be prohibitive. It has built in async support which would should help you to scale better. I like tiangolo's docker containers for this.

How long does your image recognition take (seconds, milliseconds)?

If you must stick to your current design:

1. increase timeout, but be aware that your customers have the same problem - they might time out.
2. Increase resources: More pods so that no pod has no resources left.

If you're using Flask, be aware that the dev server is not meant for production deployment. Although it is multithreaded, it's not particularly performant, stable, or secure. Use a production WSGI server to serve the Flask application, such as Gunicorn, mod_wsgi, or something else.